# Getting Error on Codepen: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: bootstrap-4, codepen

getting the below error on codepen. Not sure what's happening. What exactly is not defined and what should I change?

[image: error on codepen]

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnHideBanana").click(function() {
    $("#banana").collapse("hide")
  });
  $("#btnShowBanana").click(function() {
    $("#banana").collapse("show")
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnHideMonkey").click(function() {
    $("#monkey").collapse("hide")
  });
  $("#btnShowMonkey").click(function() {
    $("#monkey").collapse("show")
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/ganiya/pen/MWKWjKX?editors=1010

Comment: Is that the entire error output? _What exactly is not defined_ Isn't that mentioned in the error message?

Comment: You did not include JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the JS settings icon on the JS window a modal will open up and you can search for CDNs to use. Search for jQuery and select the script you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the jquery **$** sign, you need to include jquery script path.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnHideBanana").click(function() {
    $("#banana").collapse("hide")
  });
  $("#btnShowBanana").click(function() {
    $("#banana").collapse("show")
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnHideMonkey").click(function() {
    $("#monkey").collapse("hide")
  });
  $("#btnShowMonkey").click(function() {
    $("#monkey").collapse("show")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```